# Adding an Organization to Login Details MVC5 Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

Using ASP.NET MVC5 Identity 2.0.

My Application requires that (in addition) to User Email and Password, I also need to add an Organization.  So users need to login in with:

Organization:
User Email:
Password:

There is a mountain of similar examples showing how we would add the field at registration and then store it to the database but can't seem to find anything that would allow me to validate with an additional field.

In this context, an email can then be stored to multiple organizations (1 to many).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

-Update-

So, based on your approach below to keep it simple, I went out and did the following:

(1)IdentityModels

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     .....
     public string Organization { get; set; }    //added this
}
```

(2)AccountViewModels
    LoginViewModel & RegisterViewModel (added):

```
 public string Organization { get; set; }
```

(3)Register.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Organization, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Organization, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

(4)Login.cshtm

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Organization, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Organization, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Organization, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
</div>
```

(5)AccountController.c s

```
Then, I added to RegisterViewModel:

var user = new ApplicationUser { Organization = model.Organization, UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

And, it is now saving when I register a new user.

Now, it seems as if I would want to update the loginviewmodel with:

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Organization, model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

but no luck.  I get an error for no overload for PasswordSignInAsync - takes 5 arguments.  Is this going the right direction???

Comment: Update to question text based on response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Identity, this is actually pretty straight-forward. The `ApplicationUser` class that's generated by default with a new project is your extension point. It's literally the user entity for your application, and you can customize it to your heart's content.

Adding an organization is as simple as just adding a new property to `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...

    public string Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Generate a migration, and then update your database.

However, since here you want to also have an email address per organization, you probably want to break out `Organization` into a class of it's own. If there's a subset of organizations that user's should pick from, then you want that to be a class on its own and then associate it with your user via a many-to-many with a payload (the email):

```
public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserOrganization> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserOrganization
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public string OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<UserOrganization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

If you just want organizations to be freeform text, then it's a tad simpler:

```
public class UserOrganization
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Organization { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<UserOrganization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```